# Converting data to code

Tags: c, evaluation

In C, I'd like to make a macro called `TEST()` that takes a valid C arithmetic expression and prints and evaluates it. So as an example, if I were to give it `TEST(5*2+3)` it would print to console `5*2+3 = 13`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert an expression to a string nor do I know how to take a given string and evaluate it as code. **How would I do this?**

Comment: That's not the function of the C preprocessor. It's essentially a text editor that substitutes one string for another in the sourse code before the compile step.

Comment: That is not how #define works.  Suggest to get a C book.

Comment: @nicomp So why can't it substitute the string into a `printf()` call? And it can use the stringify operator to turn the argument into a string literal.

Comment: @Barmar because the code still has to compile and execute for that to work as OP described.

Comment: @nicomp Is there a reason the solution in my answer won't do that? What did I miss?

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @nicomp You implied that the macro can't expand into code that compiles and executes. Doesn't the macro I posted do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stringification operator to turn the argument into a string, then expand into a `printf()` call that prints the string and the result. My code assumes that the expression is always an `int`.

```
#define TEST(EXP) printf("%s = %d\n", #EXP, (EXP))
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew stringification was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the parsing part of your question:

The [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is what you're after.

It is the most common way (that I know of) to convert a mathematical expression represented by a string of characters into a `postfix`ed version(operators come after the operands instead of between), which is much easier to interpret with code.

Good luck!

Comment: He just wants to substitute it into the C code, and let the C compiler interpret it.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I guess I misinterpreted the question.